# Thrift Debugging: Problems with my finagle server

Tags: scala, thrift, thrift-protocol, finagle

I have a simple Thrift Server, implemented in scala with finagle:

```
    import com.twitter.util.{ Await, Future }
    import com.jakiku.thriftscala.{ RealTimeDatabasePageImpressions, PageImpressions }
    import com.twitter.finagle.Thrift
    import com.twitter.finagle.thrift.ThriftServerFramedCodec
    import com.twitter.finagle.builder.{ ServerBuilder, Server }

    object ThriftServer {

      def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val server = Thrift.serveIface("localhost:9090", new RealTimeDatabasePageImpressions[Future] {
          def getByTrackIdAndDay(trackId: Int, day: Int) = {
            Future(Seq(PageImpressions.apply(123, 3, 4,  3,  2000L, 2000L)))
          }
        })
        Await.ready(server)
      }
    }
```

This is my Thrift file:

```
    namespace   java com.jakiku.thriftjava
    #@namespace scala com.jakiku.thriftscala

    typedef i64 long
    typedef i32 int

    struct PageImpressionsSum{
        1: required int         trackId;
        2: required int         day;
        3: required int         hour;
        4: required int         minute;
        5: required string      pageId;
        6: required long        uniqueImpressions;
        7: required long        sumImpressions;
    }

    struct PageImpressions{
        1: required int         trackId;
        2: required int         day;
        3: required int         hour;
        4: required int         minute;
        6: required long        uniqueImpressions;
        7: required long        sumImpressions;
    }

    service RealTimeDatabase_pageImpressions{
      list<PageImpressions> getByTrackIdAndDay(1:int trackId, 2:int day);
    }

    service RealTimeDatabase_pageImpressionsSum {
      list<PageImpressionsSum> getByTrackIdAndDay(1:int trackId, 2:int day);
    }
```

I generated the scala thrift classes with scrooge. Added thriftlib, scrooge-core, scrooge-generator etc. as dependency. I also added the scrooge sbt plugin:

```
 addSbtPlugin("com.twitter" % "scrooge-sbt-plugin" % "4.5.0")
```

I started the server with sudo sbt 'run'. The output of the console:

[info] Running ThriftServer 
Mai 25, 2016 4:18:39 AM com.twitter.finagle.Init$$anonfun$1 apply$mcV$sp
INFORMATION: Finagle version 6.34.0 (rev=44f444f606b10582c2da8d5770b7879ddd961211) built at 20160310-155158

Everything looks fine, at this moment. I tested the server in nodejs. Doesn't work. I also used the thrift python test suite. Every check runs into a timeout.

This is the nodejs client:

```
    var thrift = require('thrift');
    var Realtime_pageImpressions = require('./gen-nodejs/RealTimeDatabase_pageImpressions.js');
    var ttypes = require('./gen-nodejs/RealTimeDatabase_types.js');


    var connection = thrift.createConnection("localhost", 9090);

    connection.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    var client = thrift.createClient(Realtime_pageImpressions, connection);

    client.getByTrackIdAndDay(123124, 4, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        } else {
        console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

I really have no idea what i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i fixed it. Two things: [@BCG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365690/bcg) gave me a hint. It's the TFramedTransport. But the Apache Docu is a bit too old.

```
 var ThriftTransports = require('thrift/transport');
 var ThriftProtocols = require('thrift/protocol');
```

thrift/transport and thrift/protocol don't exist anymore. You have only to require Thrift. I deleted also the two brackets for the function execution.

```
    var thrift = require('thrift');
    var Int64 = require('node-int64');
    var Realtime_pageImpressions = require('./gen-nodejs/RealTimeDatabase_pageImpressions.js');
    var ttypes = require('./gen-nodejs/RealTimeDatabase_types.js');

    transport   = thrift.TFramedTransport;
    protocol    = thrift.TBinaryProtocol;

    var connection = thrift.createConnection("localhost", 9090, {
        transport : transport,
        protocol : protocol
    });

    connection.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    // Create a Calculator client with the connection
    var client = thrift.createClient(Realtime_pageImpressions, connection);

    client.getByTrackIdAndDay(123124, 4, function(err, response) {
        if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        } else {
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response[0].uniqueImpressions[0]);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the problem (especially since I'm not familiar with scrooge or finagle) but it looks like you're using a Framed transport on the server and maybe not on the client.

Looking at the node.js Thrift library code, it seems as if `TBufferedTransport` is the default, and you might want `TFramedTransport` instead.

On the [node.js Thrift tutorial page](http://thrift.apache.org/tutorial/nodejs), they show how you can initialize the connection with overridden options:

```
var thrift = require('thrift');
var ThriftTransports = require('thrift/transport');
var ThriftProtocols = require('thrift/protocol');
var Calculator = require('./gen-nodejs/Calculator');
var ttypes = require('./gen-nodejs/tutorial_types');

transport = ThriftTransports.TBufferedTransport()
protocol = ThriftProtocols.TBinaryProtocol()

var connection = thrift.createConnection("localhost", 9090, {
  transport : transport,
  protocol : protocol
});
```

You might try implementing your node.js client as above, except replace with `TFramedTransport` and see if that helps.

Comment: ThriftServerFramedCodec is imported but not used. Changed it but this isn't the solution.